# AngularJS 1.6.x Dynamically Load Components with html string and ng-if="{{ }}"

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I am having an issue dynamically loading components with {{}} using Angular 1.6.x

I can load the components dynamically just fine using compile, but the issue I am facing is adding an ng-if={{}} to the html string.

If I go this route it will take what ever vm.page is set to at the time. i.e. 1:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < vm.wizardPages.length; i++) {
     var newScope = $scope.$new(true, $scope);
     newScope = angular.merge(newScope, vm.wizardPages[i]);
     var html = '<' + vm.wizardPages[i].componentName + ' ng-if="' + 
     vm.page + ' === ' + (i + 1) + '"></' + vm.wizardPages[i].componentName 
     + '>';
     var element = $('page');
     element.append($compile(html)(newScope));
}
```

Above renders:

```
<service-center-branch-selection ng-if="1 === 1" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
   ...
</service-center-branch-selection>
```

How can I call compile with {{}} in the string so vm.page is using data binding and can change when vm.page changes value?:

```
// loop through the data and inject components
for (var i = 0; i < vm.wizardPages.length; i++) {
    var newScope = $scope.$new(true, $scope);
    newScope = angular.merge(newScope, vm.wizardPages[i]);
    var html = '<' + vm.wizardPages[i].componentName + ' ng-if="{{vm.page}} === ' + (i + 1) + '"></' + vm.wizardPages[i].componentName + '>';
    var element = $('page');
    element.append($compile(html)(newScope));
    console.log(newScope);
}
```

I want the above to work with:

```
<service-center-branch-selection ng-if="vm.page === 1" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
   ...
</service-center-branch-selection>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed to "currentPage":

```
// loop through the data and inject components
for (var i = 0; i < vm.wizardPages.length; i++) {
    var newScope = $scope.$new(true, $scope);
    newScope = angular.merge(newScope, vm.wizardPages[i]);
    var html = '<' + vm.wizardPages[i].componentName + ' ng-if="currentPage === ' + (i + 1) + '"></' + vm.wizardPages[i].componentName + '>';
    var element = $('page');
    element.append($compile(html)(newScope));
    console.log(newScope);
}
```

Add 'currentPage' binding to component so available for new scope:

```
app.component("wizard", { 
     template: require('./wizard.component.html'), 
     controllerAs: "vm", 
     controller: wizardController, 
     bindings: { 
          breadcrumbs: '<', 
          wizardPages: '<',
          currentPage: '<'
     } 
});
```

Add variable input to markup

```
<wizard breadcrumbs="vm.breadcrumbs" wizard-pages="vm.wizardPages" current-page="vm.page"> 

...

</wizard>
```

This is untested, but hopefully gives you the idea.  Also, if the isolate scope has the ability to change the current page then you will need to update it to a two-way binding of course.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If I remove the handle bars angular does not bind to vm.page.  So if vm.page = 1 the markup with still only say vm.page and not 1 === 1.

Comment: @DrewBomb are you using controller as vm syntax or $scope for your view?

Comment: Maybe I am looking at this all wrong.  What I really need is to be able to render nested components.

`<wizard breadcrumbs="vm.breadcrumbs" wizard-pages="vm.wizardPages">
        <service-center-branch-selection>

        </service-center-branch-selection>
        <service-center-branch-selection-2>

        </service-center-branch-selection-2>
    </wizard>`

I would like any component to be a child.  When I add the code above the nested child components do not render.  That is why I went with the dynamic approach.  The dynamic approach just doesn't seem right.  Or does it?

Comment: I think your problem is the new isolate scope doesn't have access to vm.page.  I assume vm.wizardPages[i].componentName is a directive?

Comment: They are components.  The Wizard component is the one that has vm.page.  Inside the wizard component controller is where I am executing the for loop to add the child components on the $onInIt function.  vm.wizardPages is a one way binding:
`app.component("wizard", {
        template: require('./wizard.component.html'),
        controllerAs: "vm",
        controller: wizardController,
        bindings: {
            breadcrumbs: '<',
            wizardPages: '<'
        }
    });`

Comment: @DrewBomb you should add the page to your bindings so that you can pass it into your new scope that you are creating.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what do you mean by adding the page to the bindings? Thanks again in advance.

Comment: @DrewBomb Not a problem.  Please check the updated answer and see if that makes sense.  I'm passing in the the page variable so that the isolate scope has access to it.